# Clarification of probability bound in terms of $(\epsilon, \delta)$

Tags: probability, epsilon-delta, upper-lower-bounds

I am trying to understand the answer to an exercise for probability bounds that was previously posted on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/267618/lower-bound-on-number-of-samples-for-an-epsilon-delta-approximation-matching-the/269027). The question is:

> What is a lower bound on the number of trials you have to perform in order to distinguish two biased coins: one with $p(H) = \frac{1}{2} + \epsilon$, and the other with $p(H) = \frac{1}{2} - \epsilon$ ?

After making use of some Chernoff bounds, the accepted answer states:

> If we plug in and solve $\delta\leq P(A)\leq2\exp\left(-\frac{2\cdot\epsilon^{2}}{n}\right)$, then $n\ge\frac{1}{\epsilon^{2}}log(\frac{1}{\delta})$. [1]

It is not clear to me how to actually get from that to the result of $n\ge\frac{1}{\epsilon^{2}}log(\frac{1}{\delta})$. Are there any assumptions being made and not stated? What are the exact steps in order to derive $n$ in terms of $(\epsilon, \delta)$?

Thank you!

---

[1] Henry.L (https://mathoverflow.net/users/25437/henry-l), Lower bound on number of samples for an epsilon delta approximation matching the Chernoff bound, URL (version: 2017-05-04): https://mathoverflow.net/q/269027

Comment: I don't think it's related to the part that you care about, but this second part makes no sense: if $\epsilon$ is irrational then $P(B)$ is identically equal to $1$ independent of $n$.

Comment: The first part also seems to make no sense: if you know $P(A) \leq c(n)$ and you find $n$ such that $c(n) \geq \delta$ then there is no guarantee that also $P(A) \geq \delta$. Instead you want to go from $P(A) \leq c$ to $c \leq z$, and infer that $P(A) \leq z$. Presumably what is actually intended is to have $P(A) \leq 1-\delta$.

Comment: Yes, the entire post seemed confusing. Specifically, I wanted to derive n in terms of $\epsilon$ and $\delta$, so that's why I included only that part here.

Comment: I suppose (from the question itfself), that $\delta$ is being used in the sense of "being correct with prob. $> \delta$".

Comment: Which doesn't really make sense with how we normally use these letters (where $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ are small numbers). "$\delta$-confident", as defined in the link in that answer, means correct with probability $>1-\delta$.

Comment: Exactly. I think this is a first source of confusion. But accounting for this, how to get a lower bound on $n$ in terms of $\epsilon$ and $\delta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first, it is OK to ignore the $1/2+\epsilon$ coin entirely and focus only on the $1/2-\epsilon$ coin. This is because we correctly identify both coins if and only if we correctly identify either one, and the biases are of equal magnitude.

Now the idea is to assert the statement "the coin is biased in favor of tails" exactly when the event $B:=$"in $n$ flips of the coin, less than $n/2$ flips were heads" occurs. Thus, you want to have $n$ such that, if the coin is actually biased in favor of tails, $B$ occurs with probability at least $1-\delta$. Conversely, if it is biased in favor of heads, you want $B^c$ to occur with probability at least $1-\delta$. (You can assign an arbitrary conclusion to the estimator when $n$ is even and you get exactly the same number of heads and tails; asymptotically this has vanishingly small probability.)

Now because the biases are symmetric, it suffices to have $P(B) \geq 1-\delta$ when the coin is biased in favor of tails.

So finally, having set up the problem, we want a "reasonably" tight pair of bounds on $P(X \geq n/2)$, which is $P(B^c)$ in the notation above, when $X$ is binomial($n,1/2-\epsilon$) distributed (i.e. when the coin is biased in favor of tails).

The Chernoff bound itself gives an upper bound of $e^{-2 \epsilon^2 n}$. A less standard bound is given here: https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~nmousavi/Papers/Chernoff-Tightness.pdf in Eq. (4), this gives a lower bound of $\frac{1}{4} e^{-\frac{2}{1/2-\epsilon} \epsilon^2 n}$. (Note that in the correspondence between the notations, $m=n,t=\epsilon n,p=1/2-\epsilon$ so indeed $\epsilon n \leq n(1-2p)=2\epsilon n$, as required by the statement.)

Therefore, to make the correct assignment with probability $1-\delta$, it is sufficient to have $n>\frac{\log(\delta^{-1})}{2\epsilon^2}$ and necessary to have $n>\frac{(1/2-\epsilon) \log(4\delta^{-1})}{2\epsilon^2}$, which is "morally" a factor of two smaller, assuming $\epsilon \ll 1/2$ and $\delta \ll 1/4$.

Comment: This was a great explanation, understood it very clearly, thank you! Basically, you just look at one coin since the other one is sort of _embedded into it_, because it has an opposite bias.

Comment: Now, for a follow-up question, what if the biases wouldn't have equal magnitudes? That is, say coin 1 has $P(H) = 1/2 + \epsilon_1$ and coin 2 has $P(H) = 1/2 - \epsilon_2$. How would you define the event $B$?

Comment: @AlexandruDinu If you know one coin has one bias and the other coin has the other bias and you know the relative sizes of the $\epsilon$'s then you just want to pick the one with the bigger $\epsilon$ in magnitude (and exchange the role of heads and tails, if $\epsilon_1>\epsilon_2$).

Comment: To generalize a bit, can you do $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i < n \cdot \lambda$ and then find the best value for $\lambda$ that will give you the minimum number of trials needed (i.e. best lower bound)?

Comment: @AlexandruDinu I don't understand the question. Is it assuming your sample has a proportion of at most $\lambda$ heads for some $\lambda<1/2$ and then determine how big $n$ needs to be to conclude a bias in favor of tails? If so, are the underlying probabilities still $1/2 \pm \epsilon$?

Comment: It's related to this question: what is the _best_ threshold for the event $X = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i < \lambda \cdot n, \ \lambda \in (0, 1)$ s.t. distinguishing w.h.p. between the two coins requires the minimum number of trials. For instance, for $\pm \ \epsilon$ coins we have $\lambda = 1/2$ and it was intuitive, but can one prove that this is indeed the best threshold?

Comment: Next, regarding the $1/2 + \epsilon_1$ and $1/2 - \epsilon_2$ coins, my intuition was to set $\lambda$ to the middle of the interval $(1/2 - \epsilon_2, 1/2 + \epsilon_1)$, that is $\lambda = (1 + \epsilon_1 - \epsilon_2) / 2$ - and therefore arrive at a bound for $n$ in terms of $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2$. Can you find this $\lambda$ threshold analytically?

Comment: I wrote this [LaTeX snippet](http://latexpad.clrnd.com.ar/#75bc2aaf6219dc26d83772a1bebe8b24) and also posted a [separate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3716328/finding-the-best-threshold-for-bounding-error-probability-in-chernoff-biased-co) - maybe it makes more sense than these comments.